# Saving data to db with Entity splitting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm building Reporting system, but having problem with saving data to db (entity splitting).

My Entities:

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? DateRange { get; set; }
    public int Layout { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ReportCharts> ReportCharts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ReportElements> ReportElements { get; set; }
}

 public class ReportElements
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
}

//Entity class ReportCharts
public class ReportCharts
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ChartId { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbContext:

```
class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
    protected virtual void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.ReportId).HasColumnName("ReportId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateRange).HasColumnName("DateRange");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.Layout).HasColumnName("Layout");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateFrom).HasColumnName("DateFrom");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateTo).HasColumnName("DateTo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.OwnerId).HasColumnName("OwnerId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(t => t.ReportElements).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.ReportId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(t => t.ReportCharts).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.ReportId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportElements>().Property(c => c.ElementName).HasColumnName("ElementName");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportElements>().HasKey(c => new { c.ReportId, c.ElementName });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCharts>().Property(p => p.ChartId).HasColumnName("ChartId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCharts>().HasKey(c => new { c.ReportId, c.ChartId });
    }

}
```

In EF repository:

```
    public void Save(Report report)
    {
      assignSettingsToEntity(report);  
        // ????
        context.Reports.Add(report);
        context.SaveChanges();     
    }

    //Assign settings to Report Entity  
    public void assignSettingsToEntity(Report report)
    {
        report.Title = report.getSettings().title;
        report.Layout = report.getSettings().layout;
        report.DateRange = report.getSettings().layout;
        report.DateFrom = report.getSettings().dateFrom;
        report.DateTo = report.getSettings().dateTo;
        report.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        report.OwnerId = 54180;
    }
```

When I do Save with the above code data is save to Report table only. How can I amend this code to save data to all three tables.

Many thanks for help

Comment: I guess you need to look into using transactionscope, enter all records within a transaction, retrieving PKs as needed for other saves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work. When I save it it automatically assign new key to all three tables.

```
 public void Save(Report report)
    {
        assignSettingsToEntity(report);
        assignElementsToEntity(report);
        assignChartsToEntity(report);
        context.Reports.Add(report);
        context.SaveChanges();     
    }

        public void assignElementsToEntity(Report report)
    {
        report.ReportElements = new List<ReportElements>();
        foreach (ReportElement e in report.Elements)
        {
            ReportElements temp = new ReportElements();
            temp.ElementName = e.Line.Name;
            temp.Active = true;
            report.ReportElements.Add(temp);
        }
    }
    public void assignChartsToEntity(Report report)
    {
        report.ReportCharts = new List<ReportCharts>();
        foreach (string c in report.getSettings().Charts)
        {
            ReportCharts temp = new ReportCharts();
            temp.ChartId = c;
            temp.Active = true;
            report.ReportCharts.Add(temp);
        }
    }
```